# Counting number of iterations in recursive BubbleSort algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, bubble-sort

I there a formula to do this manually? Does this code surely return correct amount of iterations?

```
int global = 0;
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n){
    if (n == 1)
        return;
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
        if (arr[i] > arr[i+1]) {
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[i+1]);
        }
        global++;
    }
    bubbleSort(arr, n-1);
}
```

Comment: It sure does return the correct amount, as global is a global variable, which can be accessed from anywhere in the program and always has the correct value.

Comment: n(n+1)/2 would be faster to compute, as that is how many iterations you'll experience with that code. As a bonus, you don't have to actually sort anything. Think about it; the sort and swap operations have nothing to do with counting the iterations of that loop and recursion thereafter.

Comment: As long as you set `global` to zero before calling the sort for the first time, and as long as your code is single-threaded…

Comment: Just don't use globals. There are far too many problems. Have a 2nd function that zeroes a local counter, recursively calls the implementation while incrementing it as needed, and finally returns the count. **But** then, as WhozCraig said... you don't even need that. The number is deterministic.

Comment: yes, it   does return the correct value.

Comment: @underscore_d I know I shouldn't use them, but in the text of the exercise it's specified that I use global for this.

Comment: Of course you need to reset the global variable every time before you call bubblesort....

Answer (score 0):

It counts the iterations correctly, but:

- You need to set `global` back to zero before using `bubbleSort` a second time.
- The number of iterations is deterministic, and equal to *n(n-1)/2*.
- If in general you need to count iterations in a recursive function, you could let the function *return* that count. For your code, that would mean:

```java
int bubbleSort(int arr[], int n) {
    if (n == 1)
        return 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[i+1]) {
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[i+1]);
        }
        count++;
    }
    return count + bubbleSort(arr, n-1);
}
```

Again, this is overkill for counting the *iterations* as the outcome is predetermined. It would make more sense for counting the *swaps*, as that depends on the array data itself.